# Manual startup of REST-Service

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I'm asking myself, if it's possible to manually start up a rest-service in an java-ee project. 
Let's say I'm waiting for an user-interaction (like a click on a website) to publish a rest-interface. 
Does anyone know how to do that?

I only know that you can publish a rest-webservice during startup of your webapplication, but I don't know of a way to do it during the runtime of the webapp, would be nice to learn of such a way.

Greeting biro

Comment: I think you could trigger a main class that would start an [`HttpServer`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html#createHttpServer(java.net.URI)) and where you would publish (register) your REST service (resource). Honestly, I don't know how the container would behave on this situation.

Comment: If your web service is in a module or WAR which is separately deployable, you could also just trigger deployment of the WAR when necessary.

Comment: The question is more or less if it's possible to do this manually in the javacode.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018041/resteasy-add-a-resource-class-dynamically But depending on what you are trying to achieve, could your service not just return `404` if the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: Do you mean generate some rest end points based on user interaction?

Comment: Yes, the idea is, if it's possible to upload plugins to an server application in the form of jar files. Afterwards it should be possible to start included rest endpoints, and if possible jsf pages too.